# Is there any in-app chat SDK available?

Tags: sdk, chat, saas, paas

I am looking for in-app chat SDK supporting multi platforms. Do you have any recommendations?

I have tested so far as below.

PubNub: I don't think it's real time chat SDK.

Firebase: There is an chat sample but it seems more like syncing data between app.

Opentok: The sample code crashes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend [JIVER](http://jiver.io). It has powerful features for messaging.

- Send and receive media or files
- Thousands+ concurrent users
- Easy to integrate user sessions
- Text & data exchange
- Read receipts
- Typing indicators
- Powerful administration tool
- Multi-Platform support

I'm sure that you will love it!

Comment: Great. This is what I was exactly looking for.

Answer (score 7):

I came across this Chat SDK offered by [Applozic](https://www.applozic.com/). Had to integrate in my app and it was super easy to do so. Some of its features include:

1. One to one and Group Chat
2. Image capture
3. Photo sharing
4. File attachment
5. Location sharing
6. Push notifications
7. In-App notifications
8. Online presence
9. Last seen at
10. Unread message count
11. Tying indicator
12. Message sent, delivery report
13. Offline messaging
14. Multi Device sync
15. Application to user messaging
16. Customized chat bubble
17. UI Customization Toolkit
18. Cross Platform Support (iOS, Android & Web)

The open source repo link is [here](https://github.com/AppLozic/Applozic-Android-SDK). Hope this helps.